# Jqgrid edit get the Json data on the C# asp.net server and json decode it to array

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

after too many tries i give up and ask for help...
I use code i found on the web to perform the edit on the client and send the edit raw to the asp.net server. but i can't seem to get the call on the server or get the array from the grid (although i see the values on the Json when i use the debugger).
so i got two questions.
1. i placed a breakpoint on the "GridUpdateData" but never saw an exception on client and never reached the server. why the GridUpdateData call is not reaching the server? how can i fix this?
2. what is the variable the i need to read on the server? / how is it sent?

Thanks,
John.

the client code:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        var updateDialog = {
            url: "Default.aspx/GridUpdateData",
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            afterclickPgButtons: function (whichbutton, formid, rowid) {
                $("#x2").select();
            }
            , modal: true

            , onclickSubmit: function (params)
            {
                var ajaxData = {};
                var gridId = $("#gridId");
                var selectedRow = gridId.getGridParam("selrow");
                rowData = gridId.getRowData(selectedRow);
                ajaxData = { x2: x2 };
                return ajaxData;
            }

            , width: "400"
        };
        $.jgrid.nav.addtext = "Add";
        $.jgrid.nav.edittext = "Edit";
        $.jgrid.nav.deltext = "Delete";
        $.jgrid.edit.addCaption = "Add Contact";
        $.jgrid.edit.editCaption = "Edit Contact";
        $.jgrid.del.caption = "Delete Contact";
        $.jgrid.del.msg = "Delete selected Contact?";
        $("#gridId").jqGrid({

            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'x1', index: 'x1', width: 40, editRow: true, sorttype: "string", align: 'left', editable: true, editrules: { required: true } },
                { name: 'x2', index: 'x2', width: 300, editRow: true, sorttype: "string", align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true } },
                { name: 'x3', index: 'x3', width: 200, editRow: true, sorttype: "string", align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true } }
                  ],
            pager: $('#gridPager'),

            sortname: 'x2',
            sortorder: "desc",
            altRows: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '/Content/Themes/Redmond/Images',
            caption: 'Equipment List',
            autowidth: true,
            ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
                $("#gridId").editGridRow(rowid, prmGridDialog);
            }
        }).navGrid('#gridPager',
            {
                 edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: false
            },
            updateDialog,
            updateDialog,
            updateDialog
        );
        $("#gridId").jqGrid('clearGridData'); 


    });
```

( i changed my grid fields to X1-x3.)
the server code:

public static void GridUpdateData()
    {

}